# JQuery Check for duplicates within a class

Tags: jquery

I'm in the middle of a project where a client needs to create custom HTML forms. I've managed to create a form builder here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Rockhopper92/supv9019/

The user can then name each form element but this needs to be a unique name as it will be used as the actual name="" element when the form is outputted on a seperate page.

So my question is how do I cycle through the inputs with class="info" to check if the given value is unique? As a caveat because of how it is going into the database it needs to unique once whitespaces are removed so for example:

Text 1 & Text1 would show as a duplicate.

So far I have written this:

```
$("form.forms").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var total = $(".info").length;
    var x = 1;
    while(x <= total){
        //what do I do here!!
    x++
    }
});
```

I have managed to get it to identify how many elements have the info class and then loop through that many. Where I am struggling is how to compare number 1 with all the other and then 2 with every other...etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get this working. The problem was the form elements not being bound to the JQuery as it was created after the initial page load so I ran this script INSIDE my wider function for creating the additional form elements:

```
$('form.forms').submit(function(e) {
  var ar = $('#myForm input').map(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') return $(this).val()
  }).get();

  var unique = ar.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return ar.indexOf(item) != pos;
  });

  if(unique.length != 0){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('duplicate')
    }
});
```

This only prevented the form submission if there was a duplicate value in the form.